# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"’ for a file of more than 4GB

Tags: java, heap-memory

Using this tool, https://github.com/citygml4j/citygml-tools, which is called to-cityjson. I want to convert a `cityGML` file to a `cityJSON` file. The file is 4.36 GB, but i get the following error:

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` thrown from the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` in thread `main` or

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor183.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.createInstance(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:672)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ProxyLoader.startElement(ProxyLoader.java:30)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$IntercepterLoader.startElement(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:223)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:547)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:526)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:45)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:216)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:385)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:356)
    at org.citygml4j.builder.jaxb.xml.io.reader.JAXBSimpleReader.nextFeature(JAXBSimpleReader.java:133)
    at org.citygml4j.tools.command.ToCityJSONCommand.execute(ToCityJSONCommand.java:133)
    at org.citygml4j.tools.CityGMLTools.handleParseResult(CityGMLTools.java:102)
    at org.citygml4j.tools.CityGMLTools.handleParseResult(CityGMLTools.java:35)
    at picocli.CommandLine.parseWithHandlers(CommandLine.java:1526)
    at org.citygml4j.tools.CityGMLTools.main(CityGMLTools.java:44)
```

I found one solution, which would be to use `java -Xmx15G`, but i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Unrelated to just OOME the OP knows how to fix it. It's about `citygml-tools`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JAVA_OPTS` or `CITYGML_TOOLS_OPTS` environment variable which is read by `citygml-tools` executable. Or you can modify the `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` option in the `citygml-tools` code:

```sh
# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and CITYGML_TOOLS_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Xms1G"'
```

If you are using Linux you can set in the terminal:

```sh
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx15G"
citygml-tools <file>
```

Comment: I think this will work, but the computer shuts down after 10 minutes. Can this be because of not enough RAM memory (which is 4 GB, which is less than the file 4.36 GB)?

Comment: @karin if the computer is shutting down is most likely a software crash or overheating. You would have to debug it, no way to tell.

Answer (score 1):

`java -Xmx6144M -d64`

Go to command line and execute this command, it will set it to 64 GB

Source: [Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a brute Force approach and assign a very large healthy space

Grep for the line

```
 defaultJvmOpts = ['-Xms1G']
```

only 1 GiB of heap space

Also make sure you are using a 64 bit Java and have enough ram

Answer (score 0):

Buddy Another option if you are using eclipse is the following.

[This worked for me, I hope it helps you (click over here).](https://crunchify.com/how-to-increase-tomcat-heapsize-jvm-heap-in-eclipse-ede/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).